# Add PowerPoint slide to textbox with CommandButton VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have a command button and a text-box in the Slide Master of a PowerPoint presentation. I am trying to retrieve the PowerPoint's properties such as SlideID, SlideIndex and the name of the  corresponding file and post them to the text box on the click of the command button.

At the moment I have this code but its giving me an error:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Index As Long
   Dim SlideId as Long
   Dim FileName as String 

   TextBox1.Text = "SlideIndex:" & Index & "Slide ID:" & SlideId 

End Sub
```

I want page 1 of the power point to read as slideIndex 1 SlideID 1 and the file name. and for slide 2 I want it to say all two's and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command button if you like; or you can use any PowerPoint shape you want to draw, assign it an Action Setting of Run Macro and choose the macro you want it to run when clicked.

Either way, this should work:

```
Sub ReportStuff()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set oSl = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide

    ' Test to see if the shape's already there:
    Set oSh = IsItThere(oSl, "My Text Box")

    ' If it's not there, add it:
    If oSh is Nothing Then
       Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 50)
       oSh.Name = "My Text Box"
    End If

    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Index: " & oSl.SlideIndex & " ID: " & oSl.SlideID & " File: " & ActivePresentation.FullName
    End With

End Sub

Function IsItThere(oSl as Slide, sName as String) as Shape
   Dim oSh as Shape
   For each oSh in oSl.Shapes
      If oSh.Name = sName Then
         Set IsItThere = oSh
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: Set oSl = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide is getting an error. SlideShowWindows (unknown member) : Integer out of range. 1 is not in valid 

range of 1 to 0.

Comment: I also  want this to work from the master slide... THis code is full of errors

Comment: It works when you're in slide show view.  You didn't specify what you wanted, but since you want a button to work, slide show view seemed a reasonable assumption.  Buttons don't do anything in normal view.  If you want free solutions to problems, STATING the EXACT problem clearly is a good place to start.