# run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)' vba powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am using a code to present the presentation properties to a textbox or shape via a command button or Macro. When I run it I get a run time error that say " **SlideShowWindows(unknown member): integer out of range. 1 is not in the valid range of 1 to 0**

What should I do!? 
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub ReportStuff()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set oSl = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide

    ' Test to see if the shape's already there:
    Set oSh = IsItThere(oSl, "My Text Box")

    ' If it's not there, add it:
    If oSh Is Nothing Then
       Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 50)
       oSh.Name = "My Text Box"
    End If

    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Index: " & oSl.SlideIndex & " ID: " & oSl.SlideID & " File: " & ActivePresentation.FullName
    End With

End Sub

Function IsItThere(oSl As Slide, sName As String) As Shape
   Dim oSh As Shape
   For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
      If oSh.Name = sName Then
         Set IsItThere = oSh
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

`SlideShowWindow` is only accessible during a slideshow, not in normal/ edit mode. Adding the following line of code above `Set oSl = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide` should help:

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.run
```

Comment: You've already got a thread on this same subject going; please don't start additional threads.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Perhaps it's not your thread, but you've copied the code from here, no?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261814/add-powerpoint-slide-to-textbox-with-commandbutton-vba   Keeping the responses to it there would only make sense.

Comment: If you have an issue with the question itself then your comments would be more appropriately placed in the `question` section, not in this answer. It does look like the OP (not me, I'm just providing answers) copied the code from there; I'm failing to understand why you're not directing your energy toward him/ her.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, you should put these comments in the comment section of the OP, not an answer. If you feel it is a duplicate, you can flag it as such on the OP.